# Contract requires Duplex, but Binding 'BasicHttpBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to support it

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0

my project is silverlight and use Ria service.
I want to create a WCF Service,
this is my code

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
  [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
  public class MessageDuplex : IServiceSide
  {
    public void Attach(string s)
    {      
    }
  }

  [ServiceContract]
  interface IClientSide
  {
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void SendMessage(string s);
  }

  [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IClientSide))]
  interface IServiceSide
  {
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Attach(string s);
  }
```

When i defined IServiceSide without CallbackContract  this is add to silverlight project correctly, but when i use CallbackContract this error raise when add Service Referense :
 "Contract requires Duplex, but Binding 'BasicHttpBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to support it."

Comment: excuse me for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BasicHttpBinding` doesn't support duplex services. You must use [PollingDuplexHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645027%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: thank you ,this been usefull ,my service added to silverlight project correctly, but when project rebuild , visual studio is being restarted, and i can not run project